# Sum over partition reset when running total is 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that is taking transactions (buying and selling of items) to calculate the gain/loss when the running total resets back to 0.

The fiddle is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/974UVvE6id2rEiBPR78CKx/0

The units of each item can be added and subtracted and each time they come back to 0 for a account and item combination we want to calculate the net result of those transactions.

You can see it working in the fiddle for the first few (when open = 0), however it fails if there are multiple transactions before getting to 0 (eg 1 increment, 2 separate decrements of units).

From this data:

```
INSERT INTO t
    (account, item, units, price, created_at)
VALUES
    (2, 'A', -1, '$120.00', '2022-09-23 17:33:07'),
    (2, 'A', 1, '$110.00', '2022-09-23 17:34:31'),
    (1, 'B', -1, '$70.00', '2022-09-23 17:38:31'),
    (1, 'B', 1, '$50.00', '2022-09-23 17:36:31'),
    (1, 'B', 2, '$50.00', '2022-09-23 17:40:31'),
    (1, 'B', -1, '$60.00', '2022-09-23 17:41:31'),
    (1, 'B', -1, '$70.00', '2022-09-23 17:42:31'),
    (1, 'B', 1, '$50.00', '2022-09-23 17:35:31'),
    (1, 'B', -1, '$60.00', '2022-09-23 17:33:31'),
    (2, 'B', 1, '$70.00', '2022-09-23 17:43:31'),
    (2, 'B', 1, '$75.00', '2022-09-23 17:45:31'),
    (2, 'B', -2, '$80.00', '2022-09-23 17:46:31')
;
```

I need to produce this result (net is the relevant column which we cannot get right in the fiddle, it shows incorrect values for the last two net values):

| account | item | units | price | created_at | open | cost | net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | -1 | $120.00 | 2022-09-23T17:33:07.000Z | -1 | $120.00 |  |
| 1 | B | -1 | $60.00 | 2022-09-23T17:33:31.000Z | -1 | $60.00 |  |
| 2 | A | 1 | $110.00 | 2022-09-23T17:34:31.000Z | 0 | -$110.00 | $10.00 |
| 1 | B | 1 | $50.00 | 2022-09-23T17:35:31.000Z | 0 | -$50.00 | $10.00 |
| 1 | B | 1 | $50.00 | 2022-09-23T17:36:31.000Z | 1 | -$50.00 |  |
| 1 | B | -1 | $70.00 | 2022-09-23T17:38:31.000Z | 0 | $70.00 | $20.00 |
| 1 | B | 2 | $50.00 | 2022-09-23T17:40:31.000Z | 2 | -$100.00 |  |
| 1 | B | -1 | $60.00 | 2022-09-23T17:41:31.000Z | 1 | $60.00 |  |
| 1 | B | -1 | $70.00 | 2022-09-23T17:42:31.000Z | 0 | $70.00 | $30.00 |
| 2 | B | 1 | $70.00 | 2022-09-23T17:43:31.000Z | 1 | -$70.00 |  |
| 2 | B | 1 | $75.00 | 2022-09-23T17:45:31.000Z | 2 | -$75.00 |  |
| 2 | B | -2 | $80.00 | 2022-09-23T17:46:31.000Z | 0 | $160.00 | $15.00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/974UVvE6id2rEiBPR78CKx/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by establishing `cost` and every time the running total is 0. By using `lag` and `count` we make groups out of every run that leads to zero divided by `account` and `item`. We use the groups we just created and find the running total of `cost`, but only display the result when our original `running_total` = 0.

```
select  account 
       ,item    
       ,units   
       ,price   
       ,created_at
       ,running_total as open
       ,cost
       ,case running_total when 0 then sum(cost) over(partition by account, item, grp order by created_at) end as net
from   
       (
        select *
              ,count(mark_0) over(partition by account, item order by created_at) as grp
      
        from   (
                select *
                       ,case when lag(running_total) over(partition by account, item order by created_at) = 0 then 1 when lag(running_total) over(partition by account, item order by created_at) is null then 1 end as mark_0
                from   (
                        select *
                               ,sum(units) over(partition by account, item order by created_at) as running_total
                               ,price*units*-1 as cost
                        from   t
                       ) t
               ) t
         ) t
order by created_at
```

| account | item | units | price | created_at | open | cost | net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | -1 | 120.00 | 2022-09-23 17:33:07+01 | -1 | 120.00 | null |
| 1 | B | -1 | 60.00 | 2022-09-23 17:33:31+01 | -1 | 60.00 | null |
| 2 | A | 1 | 110.00 | 2022-09-23 17:34:31+01 | 0 | -110.00 | 10.00 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 50.00 | 2022-09-23 17:35:31+01 | 0 | -50.00 | 10.00 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 50.00 | 2022-09-23 17:36:31+01 | 1 | -50.00 | null |
| 1 | B | -1 | 70.00 | 2022-09-23 17:38:31+01 | 0 | 70.00 | 20.00 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 50.00 | 2022-09-23 17:40:31+01 | 2 | -100.00 | null |
| 1 | B | -1 | 60.00 | 2022-09-23 17:41:31+01 | 1 | 60.00 | null |
| 1 | B | -1 | 70.00 | 2022-09-23 17:42:31+01 | 0 | 70.00 | 30.00 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 70.00 | 2022-09-23 17:43:31+01 | 1 | -70.00 | null |
| 2 | B | 1 | 75.00 | 2022-09-23 17:45:31+01 | 2 | -75.00 | null |
| 2 | B | -2 | 80.00 | 2022-09-23 17:46:31+01 | 0 | 160.00 | 15.00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9XUUJpAJ?hide=6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte`, building up the results row by row, using a `JSON` object to store running `open` and `cost` values for every unique `item`:

```
with recursive transactions as (
   select row_number() over (order by t1.created_at) id, t1.* from t t1 
   order by t1.created_at
),
cte(id, account, item, unit, price, created_at, open, cost, net, p) as (
   select t.*, t.unit, -1*t.price*t.unit, 0, (select jsonb_object_agg(t1.item, 
       jsonb_build_object('u', 0, 'c', 0)) from transactions t1)||jsonb_build_object(t.item, 
       jsonb_build_object('u', t.unit, 'c', -1*t.price*t.unit)) 
   from transactions t where t.id = 1
   union all
   select t.*, (c.p -> t.item -> 'u')::int + t.unit, -1*t.price*t.unit, 
          case when (c.p -> t.item -> 'u')::int + t.unit = 0 
          then (c.p -> t.item -> 'c')::int + -1*t.price*t.unit else 0 end, 
          c.p || jsonb_build_object(t.item, jsonb_build_object('u', (c.p -> t.item -> 'u')::int + t.unit, 'c', 
                 case when (c.p -> t.item -> 'u')::int + t.unit = 0 then 0 
                 else (c.p -> t.item -> 'c')::int + -1*t.price*t.unit end)) 
   from cte c join transactions t on t.id = c.id + 1
)
select account, item, unit, price, created_at, 
       open, cost, case when net > 0 then net end 
from cte;
```

Comment: I cannot get this to run in the fiddle, I had to rename unit to units, but then I hit errors with summing int and money, which I am sure are fixable. It's a complex solution

Comment: @MikeB You can try out the code on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ogn4J2n9).